# Can't run Liquibase Maven Plugin with Parent POM

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, liquibase

Trying to configure my project to use Liquibase with a Parent POM.

Parent POM config:

```
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                 <propertyFileWillOverride>true</propertyFileWillOverride>
<propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                    </configuration>                    
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

In the child project I have (among others):

```
<build>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
</build>
```

Then I try to run `mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog` but I get (in the Parent project):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:generateChangeLog (default-cli) on project credisfera-middleware-parent: Failed to resolve the properties file. -> [Help 1]
```

Looks like maven or the plugin is trying to resolve the property file in the parent directory, which should not happen. If I remove propertyFile from the parent POM I get another error saying property file was not specified.

**Edit 1: my project structre**

```
Parent POM
  -- project1 POM
  -- project2 POM
```

I want to run Liquibase on project2 POM, which has liquibase dependency and plugin configured too.

How to config it?

Comment: Where should be executed this liquibase plugin? In the parent project or in the child project?

Comment: I think it does not really matter where the propertyFile property is defined. Liquibase will try to load it by class loading (so it needs to be on the classpath) or by file path (if class loading did not work). By file path can either be an absolute path or a relative to project base dir path.

Comment: @LittleSanti I wanna run it in a child project. I edited my question to make the structure more clear. I can't simply run mvn liquibase:XXX on the child project because project 2 dependes on project 1 to be build.

Comment: @Jens the property file is in a relative path to the project2 dir, not the parent POM (as it is configured in the project2 POM). If I remove propertyFile from the parent POM (which would make sense not to exist, IMO), Liquibase says that there's no property file specified and refuses to run.

Comment: Hard to say what goes wrong. Are you aware that you are using <pluginManangement> in the parent pom? Maybe you don't need the <configuration> element in the child pom then? Or maybe you don't want the <pluginManagement> in the parent pom at all?

Comment: @Jens without <pluginManagement> in parent pom I can't mvn liquibase, the command fails as the parent pom doesn't know how to handle liquibase. Removing configuration from the child project changes nothing. Looks like liquibase is trying to run itself in the parent POM, when it should only look at this as a default configuration for child projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out what is happening.

When I command mvn liquibase:whatever, maven understands that it shall run this command in the current POM. This explains why liquibase plugin complains about not being able to resolve the property file (as super POM has none).

The problem is I can't run maven directly on the child project as it dependes on another projects listed in the parent POM. Maven options of --also-make and --projects would help if it wouldn't introduce the same problem again: maven trying to run liquibase on the parent POM.

The solution I found was running mvn liquibase:whatever using Eclipse and marking the option "Resolve Workspace Artifacts". In this case Eclipse won't try to run mvn liquibase in any other project but on the child project I run the build.